# Structures and Arrays VendingMachine

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

Im not exactly sure what makes this syntax incorrect, any answers?
The assignment is to write a program that simulates a soft drink machine. The program should use a structure that stores the following data. Each time the program runs, it should enter a loop that performs the following steps: 
A list of drinks is displayed on the screen. The user should be allowed to either quit the program or pick a drink. If the user selects a drink, s/he will next enter the amount of money that is to be inserted into the drink machine.
The program should display the amount of change that would be returned and subtract one from the number of that drink left in the machine.  If the user selects a drink that has sold out, a message should be displayed. The loop then repeats.

When the user chooses to quit the program it should display the total amount of money the machine earned.

Drink Name
Drink Cost
Number of Drinks in Machine

The program should create an array of five structures.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct VendItem {
    string drink_name;
    double cost;
    int amount;


};


int main()
{

    VendItem items[5];
    items[0] = { {"Cola", .75, 20} };        
    items[1] = { {"Rootbeer", .75, 20} };       
    items[2] = { {"Lemon-lime", .75, 20 } };     //These give me an error
    items[3] = { { "Grape Soda", .80, 20 } };    // What makes this wrong?
    items[4] = { { "Cream Soda", .80, 20 } };   

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << items[i].drink_name << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the array in-place when you define the variable, or you need to create multiple structures as variables and then assign.

So you can do like this:

```
VedItem items[] = {
    { "Cola", .75, 20 },
    { "Rootbeer", .75, 20 }
    ...
};
```

Or you can to like this:

```
VendItem cola = { "Cola", .75, 20 };
VendItem rootbeer = { ... };
...

VendItem items[] = {
    cola,
    rootbeer,
    ...
};
```

Or like this:

```
VendItem cola = { "Cola", .75, 20 };
VendItem rootbeer = { ... };
...

VendItem items[5];
items[0] = cola;
items[1] = rootbeer;
...
```

---

On an unrelated but very important note, remember that array indexes goes from zero to `size - 1`. So an array of five elements have indexes from `0` to `4` (inclusive). Going out of bounds, like using index `5` (which is the *sixth* index) in an array of five elements, will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Not that it matters in your loop, since you only access the second element, with index `1`.

As long as you have the proper array, there's a "trick" to get the number of elements in the array:

```
sizeof(items) / sizeof(items[0])
```

That will give you the number of elements in the array. ***But*** it only works for proper arrays. Arrays naturally decays to pointers to the first element, for example when you pass an array to a function, and when you try to do the above trick on a pointer then it will not work. Doing `sizeof` on a pointer will return the size of the actual pointer and not what it points to. Therefore, unless the size of an array is known all over the program then you should always pass the number of elements as arguments to functions when you pass the array.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for double curly braces, write it this way:

```
VendItem items[5];
items[0] = { "Cola", .75, 20 };        
items[1] = { "Rootbeer", .75, 20 };       
items[2] = { "Lemon-lime", .75, 20 };     
items[3] = { "Grape Soda", .80, 20 };    
items[4] = { "Cream Soda", .80, 20 };
```